# How do I give direct access to my files on Hapi (Node.js) server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

**Case**: I want to keep *.js files for users of my website on the Hapi (Node.js) server, so they can include them CDN-like (i.e: jQuery, font-awesome).
**Question**: What is the proper way to do so on Hapi (Node.js) server?

What I already tried was just to link them:

```
<script src="https://mywebsite.com/myscripts/myjsfile.js"></script>
```

Or to declare route, using [Inert plugin](https://github.com/hapijs/inert) basing on [Future Studio Tutorial](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/hapi-how-to-serve-static-files-images-js-etc/) and [Hapi Documentation](http://hapijs.com/tutorials/serving-files?lang=en_US):

```
server.route({
  method: "GET",
  path: '/myscripts/{path}',
  handler: {
    directory: {
      path: '/myscripts/',
    }
  }
}
```

And then link them in html script tags (like above). What I've got was:

```
{"statusCode":403,"error":"Forbidden"}
```

I test it on [Heroku](https://heroku.com/) and all the plugins I use are:

- Hapi
- Path
- Joi
- Inert
- Handlebars
- MongoDB
- Vision
- AuthCookie
- Bell
- Bcrypt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution was pretty straightforward:

1. Allow cross origin requests,
2. Set `auth` to `false`,
3. set `handler()`'s `directory()`'s `listing` to `true`

Route, which allows every website to access static files from 
www.example.com/myscripts/whatever.js

```
server.route({
  method: "GET",
  path: '/myscripts/{path}',
  config: {
    auth: false,
    cors: { origin: ['*'] },
    handler: {
      directory: {
        path: 'myscripts',
        listing: true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In your code, you mistakenly spelled `listring` which should be `listing`